# Newbie: text replacement in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my **Ruby on Rails** app, I have a method in my helper which opened a file by:

```
content = File.open(myfile.txt)
```

The **content of the file** is like:

```
my.car , my.seat, my.age;
my.son , my.dog, my.chair;
...
```

So, I **split** the content by "**;**" like following:

```
content.split(';').each do |line|
      #Here, I want to replace the text from "my" to "her" on each line
end
```

**How to replace each line's "my" to "her" in the content?**

that's to update content to:

```
her.car , her.seat, her.age;
her.son , her.dog, her.chair;
...
```

**-------------------------- update ---------------------------------**

I would like to **update the content of the opened file** , not only replace the string when read the content from the ruby code.

Comment: This is a really basic question, searching the internet for "ruby text replacement" would have given you all the info you need. Please research before asking questions.

Comment: I put it wrong in my post, I mean I would like to update the content of the opened file , not only replace a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to modify the content of a file *on the fly*. Files can only be appended, they cannot be expanded, so you cannot replace `my` with `her`.

You can start from this basic code:

```
buf = ""

File.open('myfile.txt') do |file|
    file.readlines.each do |line|
        buf << line.gsub('my', "her")
    end
end

File.open('myfile.txt', 'w') do |file|
    file << buf
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
line.gsub!(/my/, "her")
```

Although you may want to get more specific with the regular expression, e.g.

```
line.gsub!(/\bmy\./, "her")
```

Comment: What is the difference between gsub and gsub! ?

Comment: .gsub! replaces the string itselfs

Comment: I tried, it does replace the string, BUT the content of the file does not change. I would like to update the content of the opened file...

Comment: if the file is not too huge, read it into memory, making your substitutions as you go, and when you're done write the file back out. It's heavy weight in some cases, but if your files are small enough it's not a terrible solution. I would be leery of replacing things bit by bit...if your process goes down and you've handled half the file you might have issues. However, collecting the output THEN writing at least narrows the window for this sort of problem to occur.