# Update the content of openned file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Newbie: text replacement in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965199/newbie-text-replacement-in-my-case)

In my Rails app, I have a method in my helper which opened a file by:

```
content = File.open(myfile.txt)
```

The content of the file is like:

```
my.car , my.seat, my.age;
my.son , my.dog, my.chair;
...
```

I would like to **update the content of this file** in the way that **replace all "my" to "her"**,

I know I can replace **"my"** to **"her"** by:

```
content = File.open('myfile.txt').read

content.split(';').each do |line|
      line.gsub!(/my/, "her")
end
```

**But this only replace the string when output the content line**, the content of the file does not change. **How to update the content of the openned file** to :

```
her.car , her.seat, her.age;
her.son , her.dog, her.chair;
...
```

**------------------- UPDATE (what I tried) ---------------------**

I tried the following way, **but it does not clean up the old content, just append the new content**, I would like to have only the new content, how to do then?

```
File.open('myfile.txt', 'r+') do |myfile|
      content = myfile.read

      content.split(';').each do |line|
         newline = line.gsub!(/my/, "her")
         myfile.write(newline+';')
      end

end
```

Comment: This is exactly, verbatim, the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965199/newbie-text-replacement-in-my-case. I vote to close this one :P

Comment: It is a new topic. more clear than the old one. I feel it is better to keep this one

Comment: You should update the old one to make it more clear. Not create a new question.

Comment: fair enough. I don't care which one gets closed, I guess. Usually it's better for the question asker to have one version of the question so that you can get all the feedback/responses in one place. You can always edit the question in place to be clearer.

Comment: Now that your other question is answered, you can delete this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the content back to the file.

Right now you don't actually have a variable for the file itself, just for the content that you are reading our of it.

First read the content in, then close the file, then open it for writing.

Try this:

```
content = File.open('myfile.txt').read

File.open('myfile.txt', 'w') do |myfile|    
  content.split(';').each do |line|
    line.gsub!(/my/, "her")
    write(line)
  end
end
```

Note: not tested, I'd suggest reading up on files in ruby.

Comment: You need to call `myfile.seek(0)` before writing at the end, since the file pointer has been advanced.

Comment: yep, good spot. Alternatively - close the file and reopen for writing. I've updated my answer to match that.